# oci8 installation with xampp

Tags: php, oracle, xampp

I have installed xampp on my linux machine. I want to add oci8 oracle 11g extension for php. What I do:

```
[root@cpcolvir bin]# /opt/lampp/lampp oci8
Please enter the path to your Oracle or Instant Client installation:
[/opt/oracle] /usr/lib/oracle/11.2/client64/lib/
```

But it gives me error:

```
Can't find libclntsh.so. Sorry.
```

But I am sure that **libclntsh.so** is in **/usr/lib/oracle/11.2/client64/lib/**. What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

after installation oracle instantclient, you should set the library path and let the last backslash away

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/oracle/11.2/client64/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

and reinstall oci8 by

```
pecl install oci8
```

further more edit your php.ini (my is at `/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini`) by adding

```
extension=oci8.so
```

and restart apache

Answer (score 2):

I'm facing the same issue and did some tracing.
When I take a look into this file, script file when we perform "./lampp oci8";

```
/opt/lampp_181/share/lampp/oci8install
```

I found out that it wasn't looking for "libclntsh.so" actually but "libclntsh.so.10*"

```
libclntsh=`find $ora_home -name "libclntsh.so.10*" | head -1`
```

Try to create a softlink "libclntsh.so.10.1 -> libclntsh.so" and "libclntsh.so -> libclntsh.so.11.1" as below;

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 oracle dba       69 2013-12-24 10:46 libclntsh.so -> /home/oracle/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/client_2/lib/libclntsh.so.11.1*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 oracle dba       64 2013-12-24 10:46 libclntsh.so.10.1 -> /home/oracle/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/client_2/lib/libclntsh.so*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 oracle dba 39997991 2013-12-24 10:46 libclntsh.so.11.1*
```

Never try that before but I saw this in the full Oracle Client lib dir.
One thing for sure, my XAMPP is running fine when I point oci8 to this location.

> Oracle Run-time Client Library Version  11.2.0.1.0

my phpinfo() output

Answer (score 2):

I have just installed an Oracle Instant Client 11.2, Ubuntu 12.04 and xampp 1.7.x.  Try the following steps

1. Download instantclient-basic-linux-11.2.0.4.0.zip and instantclient-sdk-linux-11.2.0.4.0.zip from Oracle
2. Extract it to same folder and move it to /opt/oracle_instantclient
3. Append the following setting to end of /etc/environment

   $sudo vi /etc/environment

   ...

   LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/opt/oracle_instantclient"

   TNS_ADMIN="/opt/oracle_instantclient"

   ORACLE_BASE="/opt/oracle_instantclient"

   ORACLE_HOME=$ORACLE_BASE
4. building the oci8.so (this should be completed without error)

   $sudo pecl install oci8

   You will be prompted for input during the configurations, input the following

   instantclient,/opt/oracle_instantclient
5. add the following line to the /opt/lampp/etc/php.ini

   extension=oci8.so
6. create the following links to avoid startup apache error

   $sudo ln -s /opt/oracle_instantclient/libclntsh.so.11.1 /opt/oracle_instantclient/libclntsh.so

   $sudo ln -s /opt/oracle_instantclient/libclntsh.so.11.1 /opt/oracle_instantclient/libclntsh.so.10.1
7. restart your lampp server

   $sudo /opt/lampp/lampp restart